# Setting an attribute to the last position

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Is it possible to set a new attribute to the last position of a html element using javascript/jQuery?**

This would be helpfull for me in a case where the attribute order is important to decide whether the paragraph has changed or not.

**Example:**

```
<p attribute1="true" attribute2="true">
```

Now, i would like to add a third attribute so that the resulting paragraph would look like

```
<p attribute1="true" attribute2="true" attribute3="true">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  Attributes are unordered in HTML and XHTML markup languages, so browsers are free to return them in whatever order they like, e.g. alphabetic, specified, etc.

You should rethink your approach, for instance using the `.data()` method to track changes:

```
$("#el").data("changeHistory", []);

// ...
$("#el").data("changeHistory").push(new Date().toString());
```

Comment: that is exactly what i thought - thx for confirming this. Unfortunatly i do not have any influence to change the comparison function because it is inside a 3rd party framework and changign that core code is out of discussion

Answer (score 2):

Optimally you should never be in a *position* where you need to read attributes in order (by index).

If you have an element like so `<div id="container">`, you can add an attribute using jQuery like so `$('#container').attr('disabled', true);`.  Keep in mind this *should* add the attribute to the end of the element.

Another tip is if you are looking to modify a DOM element attribute such as style, consider looking at the jQuery API to see what methods are avialable before writing anything too crude.  For example, if you wanted to add a style you could simply do `$('#container').addClass('hover');`

Comment: i know of those jQuery methods, i used something like $('#container').attr('disabled', true);  but firefox then shows it to me like it would be the first attribute.